# Close the port using c#

Tags: c#, sockets

Using socket programming some time it gives error that port is already in use
is there anyway to release/close the port?
e.g 5657 is my port no. can i release the port manually ? using c#
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a port that any process can use. if you want to "reserve" a port, pick one < 1024 that isn't being used, or isn't likely to be used, by something else on your system. clobbering another process probably isn't the right way to go about it.

Comment: @Thanks for help. There is problem that window take some time to release the port after close the socket during that time if try to connect using same port it gives error

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`SetSocketOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx) to set the `SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress` option:

```
mysocket.SetSocketOpeion(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

After the socket is closed, this flag allows other processes (including your own application) to reuse the address (ip-address/port pair).